# How to make font-size smaller when it extends to a parent

Tags: javascript, html, css, font-size

In CSS, for example this code:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
height:100px;
width:400px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button id="click" />
  <div class="container">
    <p id="text" ></p>
  </div>
</body>
  <script>
  Some function() {
    //code that adds 'text' to the paragraph every click
  }

  Some another function() {
    Some if(text extends to the width of the parent, then lower the font-size) {
    }
  }
  </script>
</html>
```

How do I make the font-size smaller and smaller if its width extends? Like for every click of the button adds 'text' on the paragraph, so when I repeat it many times, It would be like: texttexttexttexttext and so on, if it extends then lower the font size

Comment: After looking at your history I've noticed you ask questions and don't mark answers as helpful, correct, or provide any feedback to people trying to help you. - On this website, it will help you and justify the time people spend on helping you if you communicate, upvote helpful answers, or mark answers as correct. Regardless, I hope my answer has helped with your problem. - Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way. Run the script below, comments are within to help understand.

NOTE: You did not provide how you would be increasing width. In your code, there is a set width of 400px on the container. This width will not change unless you make it change through media queries or javascript.

```js
//Get text element by id "text"
  var text = document.getElementById("text");
  //Get div element by id "container"
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  //Get current container width
  var w = container.offsetWidth;
  console.log(w);
  
   function addText() {
   //if nothing exists within p element add "text" or if something does exist increment "text"
    if (text.innerHTML.length <= 1  || text.innerHTML.length >= 1) {
    text.innerHTML += "text";
    }
    //check the container width and increase font size based on width
    if (w > 300) {
    text.style.fontSize = "50px"
    }
  }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
.container {
height:100px;
width:400px;
}
.paragraph {
font-size: 12px;
}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <button onclick="addText();" id="click" />Click Me</button>
  <div class="container" id="container">
    <p class="paragraph" id="text"></p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```